# Laravel routing issues

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a get request to rest api, route bellow:

```
Route::group(
    ['middleware' => 'api'],
    function() {
        Route::get('users', 'UserApiController@index')->name('api.user.list');
        Route::get('users/{user}', 'UserApiController@show')->name('api.user.user');
        Route::post('users', 'UserApiController@store')->name('api.user.create');
        Route::put('users/{user}', 'UserApiController@update')->name('api.user.update');
        Route::delete('users/{user}', 'UserApiController@destroy')->name('api.user.delete');

        Route::patch('users/{user}/credentials', 'UserApiController@setCredentials')->name('api.user.set_credentials');

        Route::get('users/credentials', 'UserApiController@findByCredentials')->name('api.user.find_by.credentials');
        Route::get('users/email/{email}', 'UserApiController@findByEmail')->name('api.user.find_by.email');
        Route::get('users/phone/{phone}','UserApiController@findByPhone')->name('api.user.find_by.phone');
    });
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\CreateUserRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\SetCredentialsRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateUserRequest;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\UserEmail;
use App\Models\UserPhone;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use App\Http\Resources\User as UserResource;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UserApiController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(): JsonResponse
    {
        return response()->json(
            ['data' => UserResource::collection(User::all())],
            200
        );
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(User $user): JsonResponse
    {
        return response()->json(
            ['data' => new UserResource($user)],
            200
        );
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(CreateUserRequest $request): JsonResponse
    {
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            $user = (new User())
                ->create(
                    $request->only(['uuid', 'first_name', 'last_name'])
                );

            $email = $request->get('email');
            $user->emails()->save(
                new UserEmail(['email' => $email])
            );

            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
            DB::rollBack();

            return response()
                ->json(['error' => $exception->getMessage()], 500);
        }

        return response()->json(
            ['data' => new UserResource($user)],
            201
        );
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request, User $user): JsonResponse
    {
        $user->update($request->only(['username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name']));

        return response()->json(
            ['data' => new UserResource($user)],
            200
        );
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(User $user): JsonResponse
    {
        $user->delete();

        return response()->json(
            null,
            204
        );
    }

    public function setCredentials(SetCredentialsRequest $request, User $user)
    {
        $user->update([
            'username' => $request->get('username'),
            'password' => \password_hash($request->get('password'), \PASSWORD_BCRYPT),
        ]);

        return response()->json(
            ['data' => new UserResource($user)],
            200
        );
    }

    public function findByCredentials(Request $request)
    {

    }

    public function findByEmail(string $email)
    {
        $user = UserEmail::all()
            ->where('email', '=', $email)
            ->first()
            ->user()
            ->getResults();

        return response()->json(
            ['data' => new UserResource($user)],
            200
        );
    }

    public function findByPhone(string $phone)
    {
        $user = UserPhone::all()
            ->where('phone', '=', $phone)
            ->first()
            ->user()
            ->getResults();

        return response()->json(
            ['data' => new UserResource($user)],
            200
        );
    }
}
```

Got an error:
`No query results for model [App\\Models\\User] credentials`

As I understand,laravel is attempting to find *`credentials`* field in User model to resolve it.
Controller method is never handled.

If I use Route::post - everything is ok.

How to disable "auto-finding", so I could get control in the controller?

Comment: Do you have other `/user` routes defined somewhere? It looks like you could have something like `/users/{id}` somewhere that gets called before the route you show in the question. The error means that the Eloquent ORM did not find a user matching the query in the database.

Comment: Please share the UserApiController class.

Comment: Thanks for the interest, updated the question

Comment: moving it as the first route helped, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the possion of the route solved the problem:

```
Route::group(
    ['middleware' => 'api'],
    function() {
        Route::get('users/credentials', 'UserApiController@findByCredentials')->name('api.user.find_by.credentials');

        Route::get('users', 'UserApiController@index')->name('api.user.list');
        Route::get('users/{user}', 'UserApiController@show')->name('api.user.user');
        Route::post('users', 'UserApiController@store')->name('api.user.create');
        Route::put('users/{user}', 'UserApiController@update')->name('api.user.update');
        Route::delete('users/{user}', 'UserApiController@destroy')->name('api.user.delete');

        Route::patch('users/{user}/credentials', 'UserApiController@setCredentials')->name('api.user.set_credentials');

        Route::get('users/email/{email}', 'UserApiController@findByEmail')->name('api.user.find_by.email');
        Route::get('users/phone/{phone}','UserApiController@findByPhone')->name('api.user.find_by.phone');
    });
```

Comment: Just a note, you probably want to move the last 2 routes up as well, to right before `Route::get('users/{user}'`. Otherwise, the wildcard on that route will catch anything that starts with `users/anystringhere/evenifsomethingelseishere`

Comment: For some reason the last two are working fine. But I will move them to prevent errors in future